# PyQt5 App created with py2app is 240 MB - how to reduce size?

Tags: python, pyqt5, py2app

I have this python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import platform
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QApplication, QDesktopWidget)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication

class Example(QWidget):
    # Constructur
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('My Qt5 window')
        self.center()
        self.show()

    def center(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When i package this with py2app, i get a 240MB sized app. Is there a way to reduce the size? I don't think that it is necessary to package the whole PyQt5 module.

EDIT: Here is my `setup.py`

from setuptools import setup

```
APP = ['pyqt5_test.py']
APP_NAME = "SuperApp"
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {
    'argv_emulation': True,
    'iconfile': 'kraken.icns',
    'plist': {
        'CFBundleName': APP_NAME,
        'CFBundleDisplayName': APP_NAME,
        'CFBundleGetInfoString': "Making Sandwiches",
        'CFBundleIdentifier': "com.metachris.osx.sandwich",
        'CFBundleVersion': "0.1.0",
        'CFBundleShortVersionString': "0.1.0",
        'NSHumanReadableCopyright': u"Copyright © 2017, Someone, All Rights Reserved"
    }
}

setup(
    app=APP,
    name=APP_NAME,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Comment: I doubt whether PyQt5 itself is the problem - its much more likely to be all the Qt5 stuff. Debug files maybe?

Comment: @ekhumoro how could debugging help me here? You mean debugging the packaging process of py2app? I'm not sure how exactly to do that...

Comment: No. I meant: does the package include any Qt files containing [debugging symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debug_symbol)? These files are typically much larger than their stripped versions.

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: No i didn't. I didn't search extensively but i never found a solution